# Graylog to Wazuh

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, graylog, wazuh

I already have a graylog service that collects my logs, but I'd like to extend it with wazuh. I have the free version of both, so the graylog data I can send is in gelf format only.
My question is: "How can I send data from graylog, in GELF format, to wazuh?"

I tried sending the data to a VM with logstash and sending the data to elasticsearch, but that way I don't have wazuh benefits